# set Default routing url and attribute route ? how to

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

My RouteConfig file is

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My controller is

```
 [Route("EMS/{Employee}")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

my working url is 
http://localhost:6628/EMS/Employee

but i want to use simple http://localhost:6628 as my default url as without MapMvcAttributeRoutes() it was working fine

How can i use both of them in same project like default controller action must be employee and index and on click route url EMS/Employee working like this

```
  <td>
    <input type="button" id="ROUTE" value="ROUTE"   onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Employee", "EMS")'" class="btn-info" />
                        </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the controller for example is `EmployeeController`

```
public class EmployeeController {    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] //Matches GET /
    [Route("EMS/Employee")] //Matches GET EMS/EMployee
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can use multiple routes on the actions.